# What would it sound like if you didn't have a mouth

Tags: anatomy

Specifically, the entire chamber of the mouth would be filled with solid tissue. Instead of teeth, the maxilla and mandible would be fused together. The lips would also be fused into smooth skin, and directly attached to the jawbones. The velum and epiglottis would also be fused, smoothly grading from one to the other. The tongue would fill the space inside the mouth, from the epiglottis/velum to the jawbones, without any air-space

The rest of the anatomy for speaking is like a regular human

What sounds would someone make if they tried to speak without a mouth, as described above?

Comment: Have you ever tried to hum without opening your lips? That's how it would sound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For breathing to occur, we must assume the nasal passages are clear.

Therefore, it would just sound like humming. You can try this by stuffing your mouth with bread. You could change the pitch of your voice but vowels would be indistinguishable. The only possible consonant would be a glottal stop. You could achieve some expression by pinching your nose in varying amounts.

However, if you had controllable nostrils (or a trunk), then more complex sounds would be possible.

Comment: Note: to really know how it sounds, OP would need to record it and then listen to recording. Otherwise bone conduction of sound would heavily change his perception.